# Creating a SharePoint Quiz OOTB

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to create a quiz that users can take in SharePoint to test their knowledge. I can do this by creating a custom list with calculated fields to work out whether they have passed or not.

This is fine but the issue comes in making sure that users cannot see other user's completed quizzes too. I see you can tick the option of 'Read items that were created by the user'. How can I make sure then that I can see all items created by all users in this list?

I am new to SharePoint so any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is setting item-level permissions. Options such as "Read items that were created by the user" and "Create items and edit items that were created by the user" only apply to users with Contribute or Edit permissions. They do not apply to users with at least Design permissions.

So, to see all items created by all users in this list, make yourself a Designer or an Admin.